# Rg.Plugins.Popup obsolete methods

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, popup

Using this line of code `PopupNavigation.PushAsync(new myPopupPage());` gives me the following warning:

> Warning   CS0618  'PopupNavigation.PushAsync(PopupPage, bool)' is
> obsolete: 'You should use IPopupNavigation instance from
> PopupNavigation.Instance. See more info:
> [https://github.com/rotorgames/Rg.Plugins.Popup/wiki/Migration-from-v1.0.x-to-v1.1.x'](https://github.com/rotorgames/Rg.Plugins.Popup/wiki/Migration-from-v1.0.x-to-v1.1.x%27)

and using this line of code `await PopupNavigation.PopAsync(true);` gives a similar one:

> Warning   CS0618  'PopupNavigation.PopAsync(bool)' is obsolete: 'You
> should use IPopupNavigation instance from PopupNavigation.Instance.
> See more info:
> [https://github.com/rotorgames/Rg.Plugins.Popup/wiki/Migration-from-v1.0.x-to-v1.1.x'](https://github.com/rotorgames/Rg.Plugins.Popup/wiki/Migration-from-v1.0.x-to-v1.1.x%27)

What would be the new equivalents?

Answer (score 1):

Do exactly what the docs say

```
await PopupNavigation.Instance.PushAsync(…);
```

Comment: Oh, OK. I thought that it was `IPopupNavigation`.